# Connect people from different networks to mdf file database

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2019

I have for local connection the code

`@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users[PCUsername]\source\repos\ZermoCSharp\ZermoCSharp\data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"`

but if I want my friends, from a different network, to connect to the MDF file and get information (for logging in, etc.)

What code do I need to use so they'll be able to connect and log in?

(my database is in Visual studio 2019)

Comment: What do you mean by connecting to the mdf file? So they can read? Or do you mean external connection to your local db?; What do you mean that your localdb is in visual studio 2019? what db engine are you using?

Comment: Hey @Fared, I meant that my program has a login form, without the program being able to read it from the database or even connect they won't be able to log in.

Comment: Ok, I got that, but where is your local db located? what engine are you using?

Comment: @Fared by localdb do you mean the mdf file? and what do you mean engine? I'm so sorry I'm just really new to all of it.

Comment: Yes, when you create a database you have to use an engine. Usually for visual studio is SQL Express, to access to info of this you have to install a SMDB (System manager database). You can install it or use the console. The manager helps you to set your external connections.

Comment: I am lookin at you dbconnection and, until now, I just saw that is indeed, SQLExpress. So may want to start looking up that on Google.

Comment: @Fared my mdf file located in C:\Users[PCUsername]\source\repos\ZermoCSharp\ZermoCSharp\data.mdf


can you do a step by step tutorial or explain a bit more, please?

Comment: Do you have another way I could send you this? It is a bit hard to elaborate here.

Comment: @Fared Perhaps you got social media? Like discord or something similar?

Comment: Discord: ezekyel#0474

Comment: @Fared I sent, My name is Retr0